# SAP NCo multiple connection (to different hosts)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sap-dotnet-connector

For each site in a single port, I need to connect to different server hosts.

While connecting for the first time, no issues. But while trying to register (`RegisterDestinationConfiguration`) with another connection pool name, it throws an exception. Destination configuration is already initialized for `ConnectionPoolName1` so I can't register for `ConnectionPoolName2`.

```c#
function() {
    if (SAPDestination == null) {
        SAPDestination = SAPConnection(ApplicationSite);
        RfcSessionManager.BeginContext(SAPDestination);
    }
    rfcTravelfunc = SAPDestination.Repository.CreateFunction("FunctionName");
}
private RfcDestination SAPConnection(SPSite ApplicationSite) {
    RfcDestination SAPConnect = null;
    try {
        DestinationConfig objConfig = new DestinationConfig();
        SAPConnect = objConfig.TryGetDestination(ConnectionPoolName); // If connection doesnt exist with this connection pool name returns null
        if (SAPConnect == null) {
            DestinationConfig configObj = new DestinationConfig();
            DestinationConfig.ApplicationSite = ApplicationSite;
            RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(configObj); // Throws exception when trying to register for new connection pool name
            SAPConnect = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination(ConnectionPoolName);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {

}
    return SAPConnect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration()` is a global static method. You can only register once. It should be set in a static context (like a static class constructor) or you can use `RfcDestinationManager.IsDestinationConfigurationRegistered()` to check if already registered. The exception is thrown to prevent incorrect usage.

The registration object needs to implement `SAP.Middleware.Connector.IDestinationConfiguration`.
It has a method `RfcConfigParameters GetParameters(string destinationName);` This should return connection parameters for the requested destination.

You should use this way only if you need to look up the connection parameters from an external store. The simpler method is to store the connection parameters in the app.config/web.config (can store multiple) and not use `RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration()`.

Taken from the SAP NCo Tutorial Code StepByStepClient.cs

> The .Net Connector 3.0 introduces a new destination-oriented concept. Applications work with destination instances, which are configured per default in the application configuration file (app.config) or which can alternatively be defined by explicitly registering an IDestinationConfiguration object. A destination identifies the backend to which connections can be opened.